# How to call a method after a WPF window is closed?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I've got a couple of Controls linked as follows:

```
ProductSearchControl (UserControl) [contains SearchProducts()]
     --ProductListControl (UserControl)
          --ProductResultPanel(UserControl)
                  |
                  |
                  |
           ProductDetailsWindow (Window)
```

Within **ProductResultPanel.xaml.cs**, the following method gets called on a Button click.

```
    void OnModifyPrice(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.ModifyPrice != null)
        {
            ProductDetailsWindow win = new ProductDetailsWindow(this.productId);
            win.ShowInTaskbar = false;
            win.WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.CenterScreen;
            win.Owner = Window.GetWindow(this);
            bool? result = win.ShowDialog();
        }
    }
```

On the **ProductDetailsWindow**, if I click on a Button, I want to execute the **SearchProducts()** within **ProductSearchControl** but I'm currently having difficulty.

Within **ProductDetailsWindow.xaml.cs**

```
    private void OnCancel(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.DialogResult = false;
    }

    private void OnSave(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.DialogResult = true;
    }
```

So after clicking the Save button, I am returned to **ProductResultPanel** but I don't know how to call the **SearchProducts()**.

Is this possible and if so, any help would be appreciated?

Comment: make SearchProducts public, and call it with your instance of ProductSearchControl

Comment: @Les, I don't have an instance of a ProductSearchControl as shown in the second code block.

Answer (score 1):

The `Window` still exists, even after you close it, and you can access its public properties and methods from `ProductResultPanel.xaml.cs`. Example:

```
var x = win.SomePublicProperty;
var y = win.GetProducts();
// whatever you need and provide access to in ProductDetailsWindow
```

Comment: I don't want to access anything in ProductDetailsWindow. I want to execute SearchProducts() from ProductResultsPanel.xaml.cs.

Comment: @bhav like they're doing with win.GetProducts(); ?

Comment: `ProductDetailsWindow` has a `ProductSearchControl`, and `ProductSearchControl`has `SearchProducts()? Can the window not access the method and provide you with the results?